# RavenDb Auth Bundle. Why Roles & Users a stored in System Documents?

Tags: c#, .net, authorization, ravendb, nosql

The official RavenDb documentation is inconsistent on whether to store *Users* and *Roles* in the *System Documents* or *General Documents*.

Though it doesn't recommend to use a certain way, one article (see [KB : Bundles : Authorization Bundle Design](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/csharp/server/kb/authorization-bundle-design)) implicitly stores users in the *System Documents* by starting the document ids with `raven/`, when another (see [Bundle: Authorization](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/csharp/server/bundles/authorization)) uses *General Documents* (as no `raven/` prefix in document ids).

**Question:** What are the merits for storing *Users* and *Roles* in the *System Documents*?

Seems that permission checks (`IsAllowed()` method) work regardless of the storage. However, inability to query documents stored in the *System Documents* (can load by ID only) is a serious drawback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex,
Documents starting with `Raven/` are called system documents, and are typically used by RavenDB itself. In other words, they typically have meaningful document ids.

`Raven/ApiKeys/Foo` for example is the document that will be searched to authenticate the `foo` Api Key.

On the other hand, the `IsAllowed` method and friends can accept any document id, so that doesn't have to be known ahead of time.

This is the primary reason for the different.
Note that system documents are not going to be replicated, while other documents would be replicated. By making your authorization rules docs system documents, you prevent them from being replicated.

That might be something you want to do or not, depending on your needs.